# How to gain speed up in this recursive tree with openMP?

Tags: recursion, openmp

I wrote a small code that grows a graph recursively and afterwards free the nodes too (shown below). I am compiling the code with mpicc with and without the -fopenmp flag.

Running the code with time (time mpirun ./a.out) I get a real time of 4.259 s, but I get a huge penalty using openmp directives (shown in the code) - real time is now 10.744 s. I have been trying some settings to set the numbers of threads etc., but I do not get any speed up.

Is there something more I can set to achieve more parallelism and performance gains? or is the code so small and has dependencies between parent and offspring nodes blocking any potential gains?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>

struct tree_node{
    int value;
    struct tree_node *left_node, *right_node;
};

typedef struct tree_node tree_node_t;

tree_node_t* new_node(int value){
    tree_node_t *p = (tree_node_t*) malloc(sizeof(tree_node_t)); 
    p->value = value;
    p->left_node = p->right_node = NULL;
    assert((p->value > 0 || p->value == 0) && p->value < 10);
    return p;
}


void tree_grow(tree_node_t* parent, int depth){
    if(depth == 0){
        return; 
    }
    #pragma omp task
    {
        #pragma omp task
        {parent->left_node = new_node(rand() % 10);}
        #pragma omp task
        {parent->right_node = new_node(rand() % 10);}
        #pragma omp task
        {tree_grow(parent->left_node, depth-1);}
        #pragma omp task 
        {tree_grow(parent->right_node, depth-1);}
    }
}

void branch_cutting(tree_node_t* current){
    if (current == NULL){
        return;
    }
    #pragma omp task
    {
        #pragma omp task
        {branch_cutting(current->left_node);}
        #pragma omp task
        {branch_cutting(current->right_node);}
    }
    #pragma omp task
    free(current);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{
    //omp_set_dynamic(0);
    //omp_set_num_threads(6);
    tree_node_t *root = new_node(0);
    tree_grow(root, 25);
    printf("tree grown and now freeing the memory...");
    //#pragma omp taskwait
    branch_cutting(root);
    printf("tree is removed\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `rand()` is not meant to be used concurrently as it uses a single global (therefore shared) state structure. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624755/openmp-program-is-slower-than-sequential-one/10625090). Otherwise, your code lacks parallel regions and instead has some strange nesting of tasks within tasks.

Comment: thanks. I found several good advice from you in other questions. Is it possible to set the thread size within my code (instead of on the command line before running my code)?

Comment: Call `omp_set_num_threads()` or with the `num_threads` clause as in `#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)`

Comment: @hristo. I am sorry, I meant to say the thread _stack_ size.

Comment: The stack size limit of the main thread is set from the shell with `ulimit -s ...` while the stack size of the additional OpenMP threads is set in the `OMP_STACKSIZE` environment variable.

Comment: The normal system malloc likely also serializes. Is there a good reason to use OpenMP, rather than Cilk or TBB, both of which are designed for recursive task parallelism?

Comment: @jim Cownie. I would rather go for golang than Cilk for shared memory parallelism. We are supposed to learn about openMP in school.