# OpenMP - Initializing 1D Array

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to initialize a dynamic array using OpenMP in C but it seems to be slower than the serial method. The function I am using is

```
int* createArray(int size, int num) {
    int i;
    int* M = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));

    srand(time(NULL));
    double start = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(num)
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        M[i] = rand() % (MAX_NUMBER - MIN_NUMBER + 1) + MIN_NUMBER;
    }

    double end = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("Create Array %f\n",end-start);
    return M;
}
```

I get an array of the given size containing random numbers but the fewer threads I use the faster the function is. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: There are lots of Qs and As here on SO explaining why not to use `rand` in OpenMP programs.  For example:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624755/openmp-program-is-slower-than-sequential-one/10625090#10625090

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenMP program is slower than sequential one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624755/openmp-program-is-slower-than-sequential-one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a parallel application running slower than the corresponding sequential implementation usually comes from either the overhead of starting the threads or the bottleneck of having threads that are not perfectly independent (*e.g.* through shared data).

Here, the former is true because you are calling `rand()`. This function uses somehow global variables which have to be shared between threads. A way to overcome this would be to use a `private` seed for each thread. Furthermore, did you notice that your array is not *really* random when you have multiple threads? You could make the seed provided to `srand()` a function of `omp_get_thread_num()` to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure your program is suffering a problem called "false sharing" cache.

The article below explains it quite well.
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads

this often affects performance a lot.
you can quickly have a test. add below to your omp pragma
schedule(static, 16)

this should improve a lot. then you can dig further about false sharing.