# parallel multiply matrix openmp is slower than sequential

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm a new OpenMp Programer and now I got a problem with multiplying two matrices. This is my parallel code but it is not as fast as I expected.
For example I give it a 3000 * 3000 matrix and 3000 * 3000 and my Domain is 2 ( the random number is 0 or 1 ) and parallel is slower than sequential

```
    clock_t tStart = clock();
    cout<<(char)169<<" parallel "<<(char)170<<endl;
    int a,b,c,Domain ;
    cin>>a>>b>>c>>Domain;
    srand(time(0));
    int **arr1;
    int **arr2;
    int **arrRet;

    arr1 = new int*[a];
    #pragma omp for schedule (dynamic)
    for(int i=0 ; i<a ; i++)
    arr1[i] = new int [b];

    arr2 = new int*[b];
    #pragma omp for schedule (dynamic)
    for(int i=0 ; i<b ; i++)
    arr2[i] = new int [c];

    arrRet = new int*[a];
    #pragma omp for schedule (dynamic)
    for(int i=0 ; i<a ; i++)
    arrRet[i] = new int [c];

    #pragma omp for schedule (dynamic)
    for(int i=0 ; i<a ; i++)
    {
        #pragma omp for schedule (dynamic)
        for(int j=0; j<b ; j++)
        {
        arr1[i][j]=rand()%Domain;
        }
    }

    //cout<<"\n\n\n";
    #pragma omp for schedule (dynamic)
    for(int i=0 ; i<b ; i++)
    {
        #pragma omp for schedule (dynamic)
        for(int j=0 ; j<c ; j++)
        {
        arr2[i][j]=rand()%Domain;
        }
    }

    //cout<<"\n\n\n";
    #pragma omp for schedule (dynamic)
    for(int i=0 ; i<a ; i++)
        #pragma omp for schedule (dynamic)
        for(int j2=0 ; j2<c ; j2++)
        {
            int sum=0;
            #pragma omp parallel for shared(sum) reduction(+:sum)
            for(int j=0 ; j<b ; j++)
            {
                sum+=arr1[i][j]*arr2[j][j2];
            }
            arrRet[i][j2]=sum;
        }
    printf("Time taken : %.4fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenMP time and clock() calculates two different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673732/openmp-time-and-clock-calculates-two-different-results) and https://stackoverflow.com/q/10624755/620382

Comment: Don't do matrix multiplication yourself. That's insane. Matrix multiplication is the oldest problem in the book. Get some library to do that for you, such as OpenBLAS. Also use [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) for holding your matrices. Stop reserving these lame arrays to hold matrices. They're slow because your compiler can't [vectorize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_vectorization) them. You can link Armadillo with OpenBLAS and it'll do the parallelization for you and your processor features to give you the best performance.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist My Teacher tell me i can't use library :(

Comment: OK. Then use `std::vector`, and don't use multidimensional arrays. Use a 1-dimensional array and create an accessor function that will access element (i,j) in the 1 dimensional array. That way you make everything the fastest. Also keep in mind that more threads doesn't mean faster results. Start with 1 thread, and keep increasing the number and study the speed as a function of the number of cores, and try to understand the results.

Answer (score 1):

There are many highly optimized [linear algebra libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_linear_algebra_libraries) that are free to use. I strongly suggest you to use one of those whenever possible.

Your performance degradation may be produced by many reasons. The following list details some of the most common causes:

- Use of `schedule(dynamic)` when the amount of work per iteration is completely balanced. Omitting the clause will set the schedule to `static`, which is more appropriate for this type of parallelization.
- Excessive pressure on the memory allocation. You don't actually need to reserve multiple memory regions for a single matrix. Since the matrix size does not change in your program, you can perfectly use a single allocation for each matrix. This also improves data locality, as contiguous rows are close to each other in memory. Then, you can access each element using `A[ i * b + j ]`, where `b` is the number of columns.

```
int *A = (int *) malloc( a * b * sizeof(int) );
```

- In your code, you seem to have missed a `parallel` region. This causes that all the `omp for` with the exception of the last one, are not executed by multiple threads.
- Merge your `omp for` constructs in nested loops using `collapse(2)` as in the following example:

```
#pragma omp for collapse(2)
for( i = 0; i < a; i++ ) {
   for( j = 0; j < b; j++ ) {
      // your parallel code
   }
}
```