# Completely blank output for C openMP program

Tags: c, output, openmp

I have written the following program for matrix multiplication:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>
#define NRA 500
#define NCA 500
#define NCB 500

int mat_mul() ;
int i , j , k ;
int main(){
    double start , end ;
    start  =  omp_get_wtime() ;
    mat_mul() ;
    end = omp_get_wtime() ; 
    printf("Time taken : \n %lf " , (end - start) );
    return 0;
}

int mat_mul(){
    int mat1[NRA][NCA] , mat2[NCA][NCB] , mat3[NRA][NCB] ;
    //double start , end ;
    //start  =  omp_get_wtime() ;
    #pragma omp parallel private( i , j , k ) shared(mat1 , mat2 , mat3)
    #pragma omp for

    for( i = 0 ; i < NRA ; i++){
        for( j = 0 ; j < NCB ; j++){
            mat1[i][j] = mat2[i][j] = rand() ;
            for ( k = 0 ; k <  NCB ; k++){
                mat3[i][k] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j] ;
            }
        }
    }
    //end = omp_get_wtime() ; 
    printf("REsult : \n");
    for( i = 0 ; i < NRA ; i ++ ) {
        for( j =0 ; j < k ; j ++)
            printf("%lf" , (double)mat3[i][j]);
        printf("\n") ;
    //printf("Time taken : \n %lf " , (end - start) );
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Everything's fine(almost): It compiles, it executes, even terminates :-D (and it ***ACTUALLY*** provides a speed-up(Compare.

But unfortunately, the output appears somethinf like this:

```
[tejas@localhost Documents]$ gcc -pedantic -Wall  -std=c99 -fopenmp  par.c
par.c: In function ‘mat_mul’:
par.c:28:30: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rand’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    mat1[i][j] = mat2[i][j] = rand() ;
                              ^~~~
[tejas@localhost Documents]$ ./a.out
REsult :
...
(LOTS of blank spaces later)
...
Time taken : 
0.177506 [tejas@localhost Documents]$
```

What am I doing wrong? 
I'm using **Fedora 27** , **GCC**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: LOTS of blank spaces = 500? Because that would make sense. Step through this with a debugger and/or insert `printf`s inside the loops to see why the inner loop prints nothing.

Comment: It actually prints when I comment out the pragmas(i checked that just before posting this question). I didn't bother calculating, but the blanks should be 250000.

Comment: (No they would not. That loop only loops over `NRA`, which is 500.) If commenting out the optimize-parallel pragmas makes it work then the conclusion can only be that trying to print stuff in parallel processing is not a good idea. Switch the parallel processing off before printing, or use other variables there.

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention. It's actually printing now(The `k` variable is not supposed to be at the last loop, it's supposed to be `NCB`...)... and my speedup has gone away ;-;   . I will try measuring performance again but without using printf in either one of the programs this time. I have no idea how to use gdb(started programming recently) and the documentation looks... intimidating.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624755/openmp-program-is-slower-than-sequential-one

Comment: @Zulan I haven't yet done what you've said(or directed me towards), but I commented out the `printf()` in both(the seq. and parallel implementations) and now I got my speed up back : - D . Why in the world is `printf()` so harmful for performance I wonder... Anyways, I'll edit this comment when I've done what you said

Comment: (New comment since I can't edit the previous one anymore)Seems to have done nothing for me

Comment: It doesn't matter what you see or don't see. Using `rand` in multiple threads is **wrong**.

Comment: okay, I'll keep that in mind. Thank you :-D

Comment: If you want matrix multiplication you should use `mat3[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j]`.  `C(i,j) = sum over k A(i,k)*B(k,j).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of `j < k` condition in the loop:

```
for( j =0 ; j < k ; j ++)
```

The value of `k` differs when using openmp. Can you just replace k with `NCB`?

Comment: Yep the comment guy also made me realize that... it's printing and now my speedup is gone ;-; Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thank you for answering.

Comment: You marked the value `k` private for threads, hence it's not shared with main thread and remains equal to 0 (can be undefined behaviour I think).

Comment: @TejasGarhewal: Just for clarity: you didn't really think the *printing* would be faster, right?

Comment: The printing is not parallelised in the program, only the computation.

Comment: Don't know , I removed `printf()` and got my speed up again just fine

Comment: @usr2564301 Of course not... oh wait... I was subconsciously expecting that, wasn't I? I'm so sorry... bloody hell...